what's means scope of further modal operators?
I am reading page 315 of Parsons' Sets, Classes, and Truth.

He presents the comprehension principle in the following form, but at the same time, he argues that this does not prevent Russell's paradox. He explains that when we form a set of objects that are F, we intuitively have the notion that we are not thinking about the set of objects that are F if the set is formed. According to him, Russell's paradoxical set, once formed, does not include itself as an element, because we think of it as not being an element of itself. Therefore, he argues that it should be understood as having its scope outside all possible modal operators where it might occur. I do not fully understand what this means.
So he proposes an alternative, which is to adopt a notation for the scope of modal operators applied to formulas.

{Fx}_0 is read as "x is actually F," and in the appendix, {A}_n is described as "it is to be read as within the scope of only the first n nested modal operators within which it occurs." I do not fully understand what this notation means. Does {A}_n  represent a formula A that appears after n consecutive occurrences of modal operators, whether □ or ◇, in the notation? If so, when Parsons is dealing with F representing Russell's set, he wants to argue that (2) is necessarily true while asserting that this exists outside all modal operators. Therefore, the comprehension principle he ultimately proposes to prevent Russell's paradox is given as "□◇∃a∀x(x in a iff {Fx}_1)."
If I understand correctly, {Fx}_1 would expand to something like ◇Fx or □Fx. How does this prevent Russell's paradox?

sry
I understand now, □◇∃a∀x(x in a iff {Fx}_1) is Fx within □ but not within ◇ because □ occurs at first and {Fx}_1 say Fx falling within the scope of the first 1 modal operator which Fx occurs in whole formula.
but why now it is not allowed Russell paradox?

Hi 유준상, thank you for this addition. However, I wonder whether this wouldn't better be posted as an update to the question. Alternatively, wouldn't the last part be better as a new question?
